# Insert special characters in Scite

Tags: input, scite

Scite 4.2.2 on GTK (both 2 and 3)

In the spirit of the old <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> in Windows, I want to find a solution to inserting characters in Scite.

This is not exactly the same as [keyboard - Ways to enter special characters? Is Alt+Numpad possible? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23330/ways-to-enter-special-characters-is-altnumpad-possible) which is about generic GNOME/GTK.

[GNOME input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input#In_X11_%28Linux_and_Unix_variants%29) with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> does not seem to work in Scite. I have not tried [GNOME Compose](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/tips-specialchars.html.en) because I don't actually have any GNOME Shell components running; just GTK applications. Will that be the only way, if it will even work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this script will do it: http://lua-users.org/wiki/SciteUnicodeInput